# Understanding multidimensional, associative array's in Groovy

Tags: java, arrays, grails, groovy

First time posting and I am having some difficulty understanding groovy script arrays? (not sure if they are list, arrays, or maps). I have typically coded in PHP and am used to associating PHP multidimensional arrays as a (key => value) association. I am not sure if I am overlooking that flexibility in Groovy. It seems like you either have to pick either a map/array combo or a list.

What I am trying to accomplish is I have another associative array that is static I would like to have associated with a key -> value. (e.g. 1 - Tim, 2 - Greg, 3 - Bob, etc...)
I have another associative array that is total dynamic. This needs to be nested within the associative array that I stated above because in this list it will contain task information that the current user has worked on. (e.g. under Tim there he might have worked on 3 unrelated task at a different time and the statuses of those task might vary. So this should correlate to something like this [Task 1, 3/6/19, Completed Task], [Task 2, 3/5/19, Completed Task], [Task 3, 2/5/19, In Progress Task]. Someone named Greg might have instead 4 task.

So my question is what is the best data structure to use for this? How do I add data to this data structure effectively?

I'm sorry if these seem like bare-bones basic questions. Again, I'm new to Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map model=[:]

List names=['Tim','Greg','Bob']

names?.each { name->
  //dynamically call something that returns a list
 //  model."${name}"= getSomeList(name)


//get a list assign it the above list maybe something like this
//   List someTasks = ['task1','task2'] 
//   model."${name}"=  someTasks
//or shorter
//    model."${name}"=  ['task1','task2'] 

// 1 element multi element list
    if (name=='Bob') {
      model."${name}"=  ['task1']
    } else {
      model."${name}"=  ['task1','task2'] 
    }
}

//This iterates through map and its value being another iteration
model?.each{ key,value ->
  println "working on $key" 
   value?.each { v-
     println "$key has task ${v}"
    }
}
```

Try some of above may  help you understand it better and yes you can use `<<`

```
Map model=[:]
model << ['bob':['task1']]
model << ['Greg':['task1','task2']]
```

You could either map like latter or above through an iteration further lists/maps within that list so for example:

```
model << ['Greg':[ 
                'task1' :  ['do thing1','do thing2'], 
                'task2': [ 'do xyz', 'do abc'] 
               ]
          ]

//This iterates through map and its value being another map with an iteration
model?.each{ key,value ->
  println "working on $key" 
   value?.each {k, v->
     println "$key  has task ${k}"
       v?.each { vv ->
          println "$key has task ${k} which needs to do ${vv}"
         }
    }
}
```

Using `collect` you could really simply all the each iterations which is a lot more verbose, using collection you could make it into one line:

```
names?.collect{[it:getSomeList(it)]} 

//sometimes you need to flatten in this case I dont think you would
names?.collect{[it:seriesHotelList(it)]}?.flatten() 

List getSomeList(String name) {
  return ['task1','task2']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic data structures that are key/value lookups are just Java [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)s (usually the `LinkedHashMap` implementation in Groovy). Your first-level association seems to be something like a `Map<Integer, Employee>`. The nested one that you are calling "total dynamic" seems instead to really be a structured class, and you definitely should learn how Java/Groovy classes work. This seems to be something like what you're looking for:

```
class Employee {
    int employeeId
    String name
    List<Task> tasks
}

enum TaskStatus {
    PENDING,
    IN_PROGRESS,
    COMPLETED
}

class Task {
    int taskNumber
    LocalDate date // java.time.LocalDate
    TaskStatus status
}
```

By the way, Groovy is a great language and my preferred JVM language, but it's better to make sure you understand the basics first. I recommend using `@CompileStatic` on all of your classes whenever possible and making sure you understand any cases where you can't use it. This will help to prevent errors and missteps as you learn.

Comment: I'm sorry but all I have seen so far for adding to the map's is a value usually done by using <<. How would I add something like those values in to that map. My example that I am asking for is actually wrong. I want something more like 
entry 1 : (id - 1, name - Tim)
entry 2 : (id - 2, name - Greg)

Comment: @TheChemX Use real classes. Groovy makes this really easy: `new Employee(employeeId: 1, name: "Tim")`. This is a critical concept in JVM languages and you need to learn about it.